# Facebook Scraper doesn't see content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, scrape, scraper

I have a website http://elearning.biznesplus.pl/, which has some issues while being scraped by Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Felearning.biznesplus.pl%2F

Domain is redirected to our web server, however facebook scraper doesn't see the content. It looks like it follows the 301 redirect, however I can't see where the redirect is coming from.

Has anyone had any familiar issues?

Answer (score 0):

The page is missing some required OG tags, like `og:type` `og:image` and `og:url`.

More information:

- http://ogp.me/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images (very important about image sizes)

If that does not work even after fetching the new information in the debugger, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I fixed those issues that you mentioned, still it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: that image is WAY too small.i will add information about that too.

Comment: Fixed. Still nothing.

Comment: ok, i would suggest reporting it as a bug then, see the link in my answer.